# PHPMailer - multiple emails in same Page

Tags: gmail, phpmailer

My PHPMailer is working perfectly but my problem is that when i receive the different emails from different person´s , all the emails will be received inside the same message (because PHPMailer send emails always from 1 single email (management@gmail.com)).
Its possible to receive always emails in different messages?? Because like that its confused to manage the email.

[IMAGEM_EMAIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyM79.jpg)

[email2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spRoj.jpg)

```
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
  $mail->IsSMTP();        
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
  $mail->Port = 587;       
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;      
  $mail->Username = 'management@gmail.com';
  $mail->Password = '*********';    
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';      
  $mail->From = $_POST["email"];      
  $mail->FromName = $_POST["name"];    
  $mail->addAddress('website@gmail.com');
  $mail->AddCC($_POST["email"], $_POST["name"]); 
  $mail->WordWrap = 50;      
  $mail->IsHTML(true);         
  $mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
```

Comment: What do you mean "received inside the same message"?

Comment: When the same person send you for example 6 emails at the same time, all this emails will go to the same message.
Watch the image i upload on text (IMAGEM_EMAIL)
It´s all different users but in the same message because with PHPMailer my email always receive emails from the same email.

Comment: I see 7 different messages. It's not clear how they are grouped in the image. Do you use gmail or inbox?

Comment: On Gmail when you click in "reply" the email will not reply for the user email... will reply for my management@gmail.com.
Watch the second image i upload now...i have 15 emails inside the same message

Answer (score 1):

There is two issues here:

1/ Your gmail/inbox is grouping the mails you receive from PHPMailer. And for that, there is no solution. It's what gmail/inbox do and you can't do anything about that.

2/ You want to hit "reply" to these mails and reply not to "management@gmail.com" but to your user's mail. You can add a "Reply-To" field in mails to achieve that:

```
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST["email"], $_POST["name"]);
```

Comment: It worked, but still a little confused because only work with the last email received..and if all the messages are grouped in the same email i cant reply specifically for the first email received for example..